# How to mock inline refs in Jest & Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am new to jest and enzyme and I am trying to mock the refs of a component. I have seen many solutions but none seems to be related they way I created the refs.

my ref declaration :

```
<input type=email ref={ (input) => { this.email = input; } } />
```

and later when I am using ref in my component as :

`this.email.focus();`, i am getting error in test case : focus of `undefined`.

**Test Case:**

```
it('details', () => {
        wrapper = shallow(<Componentes  />);
        const instance = wrapper.instance();
        wrapper.email = {
            getRenderedComponent: jest.fn(() => ({
                focus: jest.fn
            }))
        };
        wrapper.find('.signin-button').simulate('click');
    });
```

Here I tries implementing one of the solution to my test case but that does not seem to be working. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you do a shallow render, the sub-components are never created. You'll need to `dive` or do a deeper render.

Comment: Sorry, I was not able to understand that. Can you please give more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to add the mock to the instance of the component itself, like so:

```
it('details', () => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Componentes  />);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    instance.email = { focus: jest.fn() };
    wrapper.find('.signin-button').simulate('click');
});
```